# How to add a y-axis label while using pandas.DataFrame.plot() for constructing a time series plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

This is my code. I looked at the documentation but didn't find the answer.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from datetime import datetime
 avs = pd.read_csv('daily_2004_2014.csv')
 avs = avs.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(avs['Date']))
 fig = plt.figure()
 avs.plot()
 plt.show()
```

[Here is the generated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYcl3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot function returns axes.

```
axes = avs.plot()
```

Then you can edit the axes in any way you want. In your case

```
axes.set_ylabel('Desired Label')
```

Comment: Actually, I have another question. How to remove the automatically generated x-axis label 'Date' in the generated image above?

Comment: Essentially the same question. Just set the label to nothing axes.set_xlabel(' ')

Comment: Thanks, and I have another question. The generated plot shows x-axis tick labels for every alternate year 2004, 2006, 2008, ... Is there a way to show labels for every major tick i.e., 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, ....., 2014?

Comment: You are going to want to use axes.set_xticks() and/or ax.set_xticklabels(). You may also want fig.autofmt_xdate(). This is all pretty basic plotting which is likely answered elsewhere, you should search around for these answers harder and read the documentation of the functions.